# Is there a data: URI-like construct for paths on Linux?

Tags: linux, path

If you "open" an URI like `data:text/html,<p>test</p>`, the opened "file" contains `<p>test</p>`.

Is there a corresponding approach to apply this principle to Linux paths?

**Example:**

I want a path to a "virtual file" that "contains" `example-data`, ideally without actually creating this file.

So I'm basically looking for something you can replace `some_special_path_results_in` with in `/some_very_special_path_results_in/example-data` so that the opened "file" just "contains" `example-data`.

Comment: You might find strange filesystems implementing what you want. You should explain why you don't want to create a file. It is simple, and quick

Comment: I'm in an embedded context with highly limited RAM and storage space, therefore try to avoid space utilization. I need to pass a path as an argument to a binary executable, i.e. cannot use pipes etc. -- To the person who downvoted the question: How can I improve this question?

Comment: Even a cheap [RaspBerryPi](http://raspberrypi.org/) is running Linux, so I still don't understand why you should avoid files. Since Linux is open source, you could add more system calls to it. I downvoted the question because I don't understand why files has to be avoided.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. In the final solution for my problem, I actually went with a tmpfs-based approach because the overhead of launching a second process just to serve a file was not worth it. / As a more general point: I find it hard to strike a balance for the length of questions here on SO. Long question seem to get ignored (tl;dr) whereas short questions like this get downvoted because the question's premise is not introduced long enough. So while I understand that you don't agree with the premise, what information should I add to improve the question as a response to your downvote?

Comment: Move all your comments to your question inside the question itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html) in `bash`.

```
some_command <(printf '%s' '<p>test</p>')
```

Comment: Thank you for suggesting this approach. Do I understand it correctly that this would only work if `some_command` accepts input on stdin? And consequently, that this will not work if `some_command` requires a path parameter that will internally be passed on to [`open`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html)?

Comment: No. Process substitution generates a filename argument.

Comment: You're thinking of `printf '%s' '<p>test</p>' | some_command`

Comment: Ah, when seeing the `<`, I assumed [input redirection](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Redirecting-Input) to take place. The bash syntax always is up for a new surprise. Thank you for allowing me to learn yet another thing about it. :-)

Answer (score 1):

> I want a path to a "virtual file" that "contains" example-data, ideally without actually creating this file.

Maybe you should consider using [tmpfs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/tmpfs.html).

On Linux, creating a file is a very common and basic operation.

Why can't you create some "temporary" file? or some [FUSE](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/fuse.html) filesystem?

You could technically write your [kernel module](https://linux-kernel-labs.github.io/refs/heads/master/labs/kernel_modules.html) providing a new [file system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system).

Be aware that files are mostly [inode(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inode.7.html)-s (see [stat(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html)). They do have some meta data (but no [MIME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) types). And any [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)) can try to [open(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) a file (sometimes, two processes are opening or accessing the *same* file). See [path_resolution(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/path_resolution.7.html) and [credentials(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html).

Maybe you want [pipe(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html), [fifo(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html) or [unix(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html) sockets.

Read also [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/), [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html), a good [textbook on operating systems](https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Eremzi/OSTEP/),  and see the [KernelNewbies](https://kernelnewbies.org/) and [Linux From Scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/) and [Linux BootPrompt](http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-HOWTO/BootPrompt-HOWTO.html) websites

Technically Linux is [open source](https://opensource.org/): you are allowed to download, study and improve and recompile its source code. See [this](https://kernel.org/) for the kernel code (it is [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html)), [GNU libc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/), [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/), etc....

PS. Take into account legal [software licensing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_license) considerations. Ask your lawyer to explain you the [GPL licenses](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/quick-guide-gplv3.en.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot for this comprehensive overview of the involved mechanisms from path resolution to actually reading a file. I will use them for further research.